# How to organize JSF pages into directories

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have several JSF pages which are categorized into different categories but placed into one directory. This makes them hard to manage. I'm interested what are the best practises? Can I for example insert the JSF pages into several directories by category but when I open the server address to see only JSF page without directory path? Can I hide the directory path?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Prettyfaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/), this would be very easy and your URLs will be really pretty (customizable). Otherwise, I think using a filter, you can hide the directory. But, I really recommend Prettyfaces, it's very simple and very customizable.